# How to check whether the code is successfully unlinked?

Tags: vbscript

oActiveWordDoc.Fields.Unlink

how to check whether it is successfully unlinked?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

> Replaces all the fields in the Fields collection with their most recent results.
>
> When you unlink a field, the current result is converted to text or a graphic and can no longer be updated automatically. Note that
>   some fields—such as XE (Index Entry) fields and SEQ (Sequence)
>   fields—cannot be unlinked.

So

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Fields 
 .Unlink
End With

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Fields(1) = "whatever"
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Fields(1).update
```

should give error